# No me borra el archivo txt

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que borre un jugador de los que hay en un archivo txt para ello creo un archivo tmp y después quiero borrar el original y renombrar el tmp con el nombre del original.

```
private static void DeletePlayer(File f){
    System.out.println("Player Name:");
    String name = keyboard.next();
    boolean contains = false;

    for(List<Player> lp : map.values()){
        for(Player p : lp){
            if(p.getName().equals(name)){
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!contains){
        System.out.println("Selected player does not exists");
        return;
    }

    try{
        DeleteContainerLine(f, name);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean DeleteContainerLine(File f, String name) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File inputFile = f;
    File tempFile = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        if(!currentLine.contains(name)){
            writer.write(currentLine);
        }
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    return inputFile.delete() && tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola, he estado haciendo pruebas con tu método estático DeleteContainerLine() y no observo ningún problema con el borrado. Puedes comprobarlo con una impresión de la respuesta booleana del método, puesto que si la sentencia `inputFile.delete()`  no funcionara la salida sería `false`.

```
System.out.println(Test.DeleteContainerLine(new File("src/test.txt"), "Carlos"));
```

Lo probé creando un .txt con una linea que contiene la palabra **Carlos**.